# How to parse visually coherent text in rendered HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The assumption is that we have access to a rendered DOM via Javascript (such as the developer console when the page is loaded).

I want to extract text from a node in way similar as we humans interpret the content visually.

Example:

```html
<div>
  <span>This</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <div>
    <span>belongs together</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My algorithm should be able to recognize this text as one cluster, if it is rendered visually coherent.

So it should output: `"This text belongs together"` instead of `["this, "text", "belongs together"]`

Any ideas how to proceed?

I thought about computing the boundingRect for each Text Node and applying some clusterization algorithm with the viewport dimensions as reference point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of using bounding rectangles and relating them is a good one.

This file from Chrome, [spatial_navigation.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/page/spatial_navigation.cc), might interest you. "Spatial navigation" is a feature in some browsers where the focus doesn't move in tab order but in up-down-left-right space. It is analogous to your problem because it works over the DOM but cares with how the links appear, not the structure of the DOM.

If you examine the primitives spatial navigation is built from, they are:

- Bounding rectangles.
- Intersecting the viewport.
- Whether a rectangle is to the right or below another one.
- Whether something is obscured.

From those primitives higher level things are built up.

Some more details on intersecting the viewport: The viewport is the area that's presenting content. You can use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` for the viewport dimension in pixels and compute whether something is visible accumulating the layout and scroll offsets of it and its parents; or use [Intersection Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to find out whether an element is in the viewport.

Some more details on obscured nodes: In general, detecting obscured nodes is hard. `display: none;` is an easy case: those nodes will have `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` of 0. Overlapped content is harder: Detect how content collides and determine the z-index of what is on top. Hardest is near-transparent content, 
low contrast content, and heavily filtered or transformed content.

If you encounter a lot of tricky cases like this it might be simpler to capture the screen and perform OCR on it. This takes advantage of the browser's rendering pipeline to do all of the transforms and layering; you can find text in images; etc. The downside is the [getDisplayMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) API doesn't work in all browsers yet and it interrupts the user with a prompt.

You can still look to OCR algorithms for inspiration. OCR has to perform a similar problem: once localized characters have been recognized they have to be put into lines of text.

Comment: Thanks for the input. What exactly do you mean by intersecting the viewport? Can you give me an example? And how would you detect obscured nodes? Via `node.style.display === 'none'` ?

Comment: I expanded the answer with some of those details.

Answer (score 1):

you can get your elements with `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName`, this will return elements array and You need to use loop for every element. And in javascript use `innerText` prop to get text in the element.

```
var msg = "";
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(i = 0; i < els.length; i++){ 
    msg += els[i].innerText;
}
console.log(msg);
```